# How to identify user when my callback url is called during oauth so that i can store details in DB?

Tags: oauth, amazon-selling-partner-api

I am trying to implement oauth for amazon sellers in my application. I need to identify the user when amazon sp api callback my redirect url so that i could store the details in DB. This process follows oauth 1.0.

How to identify who initiated the oauth flow in my application?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.